# pointer casting (ptrCast) of child type embed in Zig

Tags: zig

I wonder if it's safe in Zig to cast a pointer from a child struct to a parent struct embedded in the child.

Something like that:

```
const std = @import("std");

const Parent = struct {
    age: u8,

    fn init(age: u8) Parent {
        return .{ .age = age };
    }
};

const Child = struct {
    parent: Parent, // Parent field must be the first one
    some_other_field: bool = true,

    fn init(age: u8) Child {
        const p = Parent.init(age);
        return .{ .parent = p };
    }
};

test "inheritance" {
    const child = Child.init(20);

    // casting to Parent and retrieve value
    const parent_ptr = @ptrCast(*Parent, &child);
    try std.testing.expect(parent_ptr.age == 20);
}
```

It's working well like that.

But if I swap field order for `Child`, putting `parent` in second position, it does not work anymore, returning instead the value of `some_other_field`. So the order of the fields seems to be fundamental here.

The Zig Documentation says *Zig gives no guarantees about the order of fields and the size of the struct but the fields are guaranteed to be ABI-aligned*. I'm talking here of normal structs, not `extern` or `packed`.

So I wonder if it's safe to do as in the example above, as the order of fields has no guaranty in normal structs?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is, in fact, not safe. As an implementation detail, at the time of writing, it has the same layout details as an extern struct, but the compiler can take liberties and reorganize the struct fields in memory however it sees fit.
A more appropriate alternative would be `@fieldParentPtr`:

```
const std = @import("std");

const Foo = struct {
    value: u32 = 0,
};
const Bar = struct {
    foo: Foo = .{},
    hash: u32 = 1,
};

test {
    var bar: Bar = .{};
    const p_foo: *Foo = &bar.foo;
    const p_bar: *Bar = @fieldParentPtr(Bar, "foo", p_foo);
    try std.testing.expectEqual(&bar, p_bar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was thinking too, it works as an implementation detail. In my use case I don't think `@fieldParentPtr` will do the job, as I want to retrieve `Foo` from `Bar`, and not the reverse.

Comment: @umcisou In that case, you should just access the field itself, instead of trying to do anything fancy. As it pertains to Zig, composition > inheritance (in that it's a lot simpler).

Comment: Yes of course. In my case I don't have the type `Bar` at runtime, just an undetermined pointer and the type `Foo` ((it's a callback from v8 engine), without knowing if the pointer refers to `Foo` or `Bar` (or any other type upwards). That's why it was nice to just `@ptrCast` to `Foo`  but it requires a memory layout where fields order is guarantied (like `extern` or `packed`). Anyway I find a solution, thanks for confirming that it was not safe with standard structs.